# Validate md5 of file

Tags: cmd, md5

I want to make a batch file that:

1. Set a md5 to variable “temp”
2. Get md5 of a new file and set it to “newmd5”
3. Compare temp to newmd5
4. Echo “ok” if equal. Else echo “wrong file”

This is what I wrote so far:

```
@ECHO OFF
set temp=202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70
CertUtil -hashfile test123.txt MD5
PAUSE
```

This is the result:

```
MD5 hash of test123.txt:
202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70

CertUtil: -hashfile command completed successfully.

Press any key to continue..
```

I'm stuck with set the output md5 in “newmd5” variable and compare it to temp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your question can be reduced to "how to put the MD5 given by `certutil` to a variable?"

That can be done by a `for /f` loop:

```
set "test="
for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%a in ('certutil -hashfile test123.txt MD5') do if not defined test set "test=%%a"
set "test=%test: =%"
```

`"skip=1"` will skip the first line (`MD5 has of ...`), `if not defined` takes care that only the second line (the hash) is considered, ignoring the third line (`CertUtil: -hashfile command completed successfully.`)

I guess you don't need help with the `if` command to compare the two variables.

Comment: Thanks it’s work great on windows 10. But in windows 7 or xp the md5 seperated with spaces for example f9 8b ae 8f..... in this case the resault is only “f9” how it can be fixed for this cases?